# how to make backup between two elastic cluster

Tags: elasticsearch, backup

we have two 6 nodes es cluster . A cluser and b cluster，two self-manager cluster on our machine

how can i backup between  A and B

A cluster is our product environment cluster , B is our backup environment cluster .

es-version is 7.6.2, cluster nodes num is 6

cluster machine is 64G ,disk is 6Tb, and the data is 5TB

tThe backup cycle is once a month

Comment: Is it self managed, aws managed ? some ore info can be helpful to understand what is the best possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can try aws s3 backup repository, this way you can snapshot/restore indices between clusters that use same s3 repository